# Unable to connect CentOS VM x86 machine to the internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I have 2 VMs created under Virtual Box, 
One - CentOS VM x86 machine
Two - Ubuntu VM x86 machine.

Both have the same **Network** configuration. However, i am able to access internet under Ubuntu VM and not able to access internet in the CentOS VM. Below are the screenshot of both VMs configuration-

CentOS VM's config-
[image]

Ubuntu VM's config-
[image]

Comment: Change network to NAT mode.

Comment: @biswapriyo,: What's the logic?

Comment: Bridged mode requires different IP from the host machine but same subnet. By changing it to NAT mode, the IP in VM is manged by VirtualBox internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need to be able to access the VMs from inside your network, then NAT works fine for both VMs.

If you do need to be able the VMs from your network, then you use bridged networking and set a static IP inside each VM.